# How to port ScrollView written in kotlin to flutter

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

Scrolling view with scaling and panning in Kotlin.
I would like to port this to flutter, but GestureLisner is not working and I don't know how to solve it.
The XML Layout itself is displayed, but the GestureLisner for scaling and panning is not detected.
Can anyone help me with a solution?

Below is the code created in Kotlin.
We are aiming to port this.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var mScaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector
private lateinit var mPanGestureDetector: GestureDetector

private var mScaleFactor = 1.0f
private var mTranslationX = 0f
private var mTranslationY = 0f
private var mImageWidth = 0f
private var mImageHeight = 0f
private var mDefaultImageWidth = 0f
private var mDefaultImageHeight = 0f
private var mViewPortWidth = 0f
private var mViewPortHeight = 0f

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    mImageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.hongkong))

    mScaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, ScaleListener())
    mPanGestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, PanListener())

    val viewTreeObserver = mImageView.viewTreeObserver
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                mImageView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                val imageAspectRatio = mImageView.drawable.intrinsicHeight.toFloat() / mImageView.drawable.intrinsicWidth.toFloat()
                val viewAspectRatio = mImageView.height.toFloat() / mImageView.width.toFloat()

                mImageWidth =  scrollView.height.toFloat()
                mImageHeight =  scrollView.height.toFloat()

                mDefaultImageWidth = mImageWidth
                mDefaultImageHeight = mImageHeight

                mViewPortWidth = mImageView.width.toFloat()
                mViewPortHeight = mImageView.height.toFloat()
            }
        })
    }
}


override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    mScaleGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
    mPanGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)

    return mPanGestureDetector!!.onTouchEvent(event)
}

private inner class PanListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    override fun onScroll(
        e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent,
        distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val translationX = mTranslationX - distanceX
        val translationY = mTranslationY - distanceY

        adjustTranslation(translationX, translationY)

        return true
    }
}

private inner class ScaleListener : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
    override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
        mScaleFactor *= mScaleGestureDetector.scaleFactor
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f))
        mImageView.scaleX = mScaleFactor
        mImageView.scaleY = mScaleFactor
        mImageWidth = mDefaultImageWidth * mScaleFactor
        mImageHeight = mDefaultImageHeight * mScaleFactor

        adjustTranslation(mTranslationX, mTranslationY)

        return true
    }
}

private fun adjustTranslation(translationX: Float, translationY: Float) {
    val translationXMargin = Math.abs((mImageWidth - mViewPortWidth) / 2)
    val translationYMargin = Math.abs((mImageHeight - mViewPortHeight) / 2)

    if (translationX < 0) {
        mTranslationX = Math.max(translationX, -translationXMargin)
    } else {
        mTranslationX = Math.min(translationX, translationXMargin)
    }

    if (mTranslationY < 0) {
        mTranslationY = Math.max(translationY, -translationYMargin)
    } else {
        mTranslationY = Math.min(translationY, translationYMargin)
    }

    scrollview.translationX = mTranslationX
    scrollview.translationY = mTranslationY
}
}
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                android:src="@drawable/comic_2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_02" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_03" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_04" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_05" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_image"
                android:src="@drawable/thumb_06" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
 import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
 
 void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
 }
 
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
   // This widget is the root of your application.
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       title: 'Flutter Demo',
       theme: ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       ),
       home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
     );
   }
 }
 
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
 
   final String title;
 
   @override
   State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }
 
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
     const String viewType = '<plugins-scroll_widget>';
     const Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};
 
     return PlatformViewLink(
         viewType: viewType,
         surfaceFactory:
             (context, controller) {
           return AndroidViewSurface(
             controller: controller as AndroidViewController,
             gestureRecognizers: const <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
             hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.translucent,
           );
         },
         onCreatePlatformView: (params) {
           return PlatformViewsService.initSurfaceAndroidView(
             id: params.id,
             viewType: viewType,
             layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
             creationParams: creationParams,
             creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
             onFocus: () {
               params.onFocusChanged(true);
             },
           )
             ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
             ..create();
         },
       );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Share your dart code too.

Comment: Added.
Almost the same as in the documentation.